# Having trouble with cross domain CORS request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cors

I am using PHP for server-side and Backbone.js on front end. I can do GET and POST requests, but can't seem to get a PUT or DELETE to work.

I am not 100% sure where the best place to put headers  are. I have them in two places. One in the .htaccess file as follows.

```
#Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.fitnesstimer.dev"                   
#Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
#Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, Content-Type,X-Custom-Header"
#header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
```

Then in the header of my Controller I have this.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.fitnesstimer.dev');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept,   Authorization, X-Request-With, X-Custom-Header');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

My AJAX call looks like this.

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: 'http://www.fitnesstimerapi.dev/user/deleteuser/' + userId,
        contentType: "application/json",
        xhrFields: {withCredentials: true },
        dataType: "text",
        success: function() {
            alert(  'User removed!' );
        },
        error: function( err ) {
            console.log( "ERROR: ", err );
        }
    });
```

I have tried both PUT and DELETE as the type and neither works. I get the following error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.fitnesstimerapi.dev/user/deleteuser/11. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404
```

Comment: The mention of "preflight" in the error means that the browser is sending the "OPTIONS" command and not getting the answer it expects from your server.  Does your PHP properly implement the "OPTIONS" request as part of your CORS support?

Comment: I am sure it doesn't and I wouldn't know how to do that.

Comment: Oh DUDE, you helped just by saying "Does your PHP properly implement the "OPTIONS" request as part of your CORS support?"

I was able to do a search based on that and I found this link. http://www.dinochiesa.net/?p=754

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment by [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846231/having-trouble-with-cross-domain-cors-request/33847163#comment55457461_33846231):

> The mention of "preflight" in the error means that the browser is sending the "OPTIONS" command and not getting the answer it expects from your server. Does your PHP properly implement the "OPTIONS" request as part of your CORS support

I found the answer.
I added this to my index.php file.

```
    // respond to preflights
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
      // return only the headers and not the content
      // only allow CORS if we're doing a GET - i.e. no saving for now.
      if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']) &&
         $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' &&
         isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) &&
         is_approved($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
    }
    exit;
}
```